# Manual tag ordering

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

After I put some tags in a question in a certain order, the site sorts them as it finds best (sort of 'from the more to the less general', probably). At the same time, it seems that the order has importance. For example, the very first tag is prefixed to the question title in my browser bar.
I don't know if there are other effects: are there?

I can see the rationale behind putting more general tags before, but personally I probably prefer exluding a 'related but not necessarily the main focus' tag than having it right before my title (because it seems like I wanted it there).

So, would it be possible to manually specify tags' order?
Should I stop caring about what is the first tag, since everybody know its being there means nothing?

If an example is helpful: [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290768/why-are-neutrons-preferred-for-measuring-cosmic-flux-forbush) is, first of all, a question about cosmic rays and neutrons, and I would be okay in having any of them as the first tag. I assume the answer could be related to the way primary cosmics interact with atmosphere, thus 'atmospheric-science', but I don't see it as the perfect 'first tag'. Would deleting it the correct thing to do? At the beginning I added 'experimental-physics' for quite the same reason, but then deleted it because it struck as the first tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [not possible to manually specify the tag order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109531/how-do-i-edit-the-order-of-tags-on-a-question) (and [second reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77808/does-it-matter-the-order-you-tag-your-question)). They are ordered by popularity, from most-used to least-used, and the first one is included in the page title for search engine optimization.

The SE team has never expressed any interest in making it possible to specify tag ordering manually, so I would not expect this to be implemented.

For what it's worth, I would advise you *not* to add or remove tags based on their order, or to try to get a particular tag to show up first. Just use the tags that apply to the question.

Comment: Oh, right, I should have looked for this also in the general site. Anyway, thank you, got it.